# Object-Oriented Programming - Public reference for a private struct of bitfields

Tags: c++, c++11

In the code below, I am trying to access the private field (contamination_levels) of a class (Apartment) from its parent class (Building). In this situation, I don't think friend functions can help because I'm using inheritance, but correct me if I am wrong.

```
template<typename T>
struct Building {
    operator uint32_t() const {
        return (static_cast<T const *>(this)->contamination_levels);
    }
    void operator=(uint32_t const cl) {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->contamination_levels = cl;
    }
};


struct Apartment: Building<Apartment> {
    using Building<Apartment>::operator=;

public:
    Apartment(uint32_t const c = 0) : contamination_levels(c) {}

    uint32_t getAContLevel() {
        return roomA;
    }
    uint32_t getBContLevel() {
        return roomB;
    }
    uint32_t getCContLevel() {
        return roomC;
    }

private:
    union {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t roomA : 4;
            uint32_t : 4;
            uint32_t roomB : 4;
            uint32_t : 4;
            uint32_t roomC : 8;
            uint32_t : 8;
        };
        uint32_t contamination_levels;
    };
};


int main() {
    Apartment  Bayview2000 = 0x74352;
    uint32_t cont_level = Bayview2000;
}
```

When line 2 of main() runs, it calls the cast operator uint32_t(), defined in the Building class. The problem arises when the private field, contamination_levels, is being accessed from Building.

Dealing with private fields was not a problem before when all fields were public.

Comment: Notice that your `union` usage is invalid in C++ (only active field can be read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try friend? It works. Test it and you will see it.

```
template<typename T>
struct Building
{
   operator uint32_t() const
   {
      return ( static_cast<T const *>( this )->contamination_levels );
   }
   void operator=( uint32_t const cl )
   {
      static_cast<T*>( this )->contamination_levels = cl;
   }
};


struct Apartment : Building<Apartment>
{
   // friend works.
   template<typename T> friend struct Building;

   using Building<Apartment>::operator=;

public:
   Apartment( uint32_t const c = 0 ) : contamination_levels( c )
   {
   }

   uint32_t getAContLevel()
   {
      return roomA;
   }
   uint32_t getBContLevel()
   {
      return roomB;
   }
   uint32_t getCContLevel()
   {
      return roomC;
   }

private:
   union
   {
      struct
      {
         uint32_t roomA : 4;
         uint32_t : 4;
                    uint32_t roomB : 4;
                    uint32_t : 4;
                               uint32_t roomC : 8;
                               uint32_t : 8;
      };
      uint32_t contamination_levels;
   };
};


int main()
{
   Apartment  Bayview2000 = 0x74352;
   uint32_t cont_level = Bayview2000;

   return 0;
}
```

But a better way would be to use public get and set functions, if this fits for you (if you don't want to hide these functionality):

```
template<typename T>
struct Building
{
   operator uint32_t() const
   {
      return ( static_cast<T const *>( this )->getContaminationLevels() );
   }
   void operator=( uint32_t const cl )
   {
      static_cast<T*>( this )->setContaminationLevels( cl );
   }
};


struct Apartment : Building<Apartment>
{
   using Building<Apartment>::operator=;

public:
   Apartment( uint32_t const c = 0 ) : contamination_levels( c )
   {
   }

   uint32_t getAContLevel()
   {
      return roomA;
   }
   uint32_t getBContLevel()
   {
      return roomB;
   }
   uint32_t getCContLevel()
   {
      return roomC;
   }

   uint32_t getContaminationLevels() const
   {
      return contamination_levels;
   }

   uint32_t setContaminationLevels( uint32_t cl )
   {
      contamination_levels = cl;
   }

private:
   union
   {
      struct
      {
         uint32_t roomA : 4;
         uint32_t : 4;
                    uint32_t roomB : 4;
                    uint32_t : 4;
                               uint32_t roomC : 8;
                               uint32_t : 8;
      };
      uint32_t contamination_levels;
   };
};


int main()
{
   Apartment  Bayview2000 = 0x74352;
   uint32_t cont_level = Bayview2000;

   return 0;
}
```